# How do I set up a PlayFramework project using the mill build tool, and without using SBT?

Tags: scala, playframework, mill

Here is how I currently set up a PlayFramework project for use with `mill`:

1. Create a folder: `/path/to/play-scala-seed-mill/` and cd into that folder.
2. Create a `build.sc` file in this folder, according to the instructions in [the official documentation for PlayFramework support](http://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/page/contrib-modules.html#play-framework).
3. This is the part I don't like: to create the folder structure and add files for Play, I run `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` as per [Play's official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/getting-started). Is there a more `mill`-ish way to do this?
4. Remove the SBT related code from the new folder created under `/path/to/play-scala-seed-mill/` as a result of the above command.
5. Create an idea project using the command `mill mill.scalalib.GenIdea/idea`.

How can I do this without using SBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a new ***Mill*** project without any *SBT*, I can think of these two possibilities:

**Start from scratch**

I usually start with an empty folder and add an empty `build.sc`.

To setup the few needed folders and configurations is sometime faster than to remove all the stuff not needed in the Template.

**Create your own Giter8 Template**

If you start a lot of Projects - you can create your own *Giter8* Template.

This is straight forward and there is also a command-line tool that works without sbt.

For example:

```
g8 playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

Creates the Play Template you already used.

See here for more information: http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/