# How to get mill to hot-reload a PlayFramework application in dev mode (like SBT's ~run command)?

Tags: scala, playframework, mill

I have set up a PlayFramework project with mill (version 0.5.2), as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106507/how-do-i-set-up-a-playframework-project-using-the-mill-build-tool-and-without-u). The [official documentation for mill](http://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/page/contrib-modules.html#play-framework) lists some commands for running the application, but these commands (a) run only in PROD mode, and (b) do not hot reload any changes to the Twirl templates.

I use the following command to start the application

```
mill -w core.start
```

When I make changes to `index.scala.html`, I have to manually reload the browser in order to see the changes.

How can I have hot reloading of a PlayFramework application with mill?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command.

> mill -w core.runBackground

[References](https://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/page/contrib-modules.html)